# Remove junk word from large sized token in NLTK

Tags: python-3.x, nlp, nltk, list-comprehension

I am stuck with processing large size text file..

Scenario: The text file is converted to token and its a list,whose length is 250000

And I want to remove the junk word from it. For which I am using nltk and list comprehension.

But for list size 100 its list comprehension takes 10sec.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords,words

strt_time = time.time()
no_junk = [x for x in vocab_temp if x in words.words()]
print(time.time() - strt_time)
9.56
```

so for complete set it would be hours.

how to optimize this?

Comment: Take a look at https://www.kaggle.com/alvations/basic-nlp-with-nltk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because in your list comprehension, you are calling `words.words()` each iteration. Since this doesn't change for each comparison, you can just move this outside the loop.

```
from nltk.corpus import stopwords,words
import nltk

nltk.download('words')

vocab_temp =  ['hello world'] * 100
keep_words = words.words() 

[x for x in vocab_temp if x in keep_words]
```